# How to center elements that have float inside one <div>?

Tags: html, css

I need to fix a problem on an existing web page, I need to center elements that have `float : left;` inside one big `<div>`. I don't want to remove the floating, and I'm wondering what is the best way to center those elements and make them on two rows.

```css
.big {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: gold;
}
.a {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">
  <div class="a">1</div>
  <div class="a">2</div>
  <div class="a">3</div>
  <div class="a">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you need to use `float`, also do you want to center horizontally or vertically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating makes this weird. Otherwise

```css
.big{
  width:150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: gold;
  text-align: center;
}

.a{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px auto;
  width:50px;
  height:20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">
  <div class="a">1
  </div>
  
  <div class="a">2
  </div>
  
  <div class="a">3
  </div>
  
  <div class="a">4
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use flexbox.

```css
.big{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: gold;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.a {
  flex: 0 0 35%;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">
  <div class="a">1
  </div>
  
  <div class="a">2
  </div>
  
  <div class="a">3
  </div>
  
  <div class="a">4
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a point in floating if you do have no intention of wanting to float to the top and to the left. You need to master the use of both  `position` and `display`  properties. This I believe is what you are looking for. I have put explanations underneath explaining what the relevant display and position properties, as well as why I used what I did.

```html
.big {
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 background: gold;
}
.a {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;  
  display:inline-block; 
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Positioning is how the element is positioned in the document. The options in CSS are either static, relative, absolute, fixed.

Static: This is the browser default. It is not affected by positioning, and will just be positioned in the natural flow of the page.

Relative: Will cause element to be positioned **relative** to it's initial position. (i.e.: if the element is positioned at X (initial position), then will be moved depending on what properties put in)

Absolute: Will cause element to be positioned relative to next parent element. An important thing to note about this is that elements are removed from the flow of the page meaning that it is possible to have multiple elements stack on top of one another.

Fixed: Will cause element to be fixed relative to the browser window, commonly known as viewport itself. If you scroll down, the position will be **fixed**, hence the name.

**Display**

This is how the browser will treat the type of "box"/element that is used (all elements can be considered boxes, as per the box model).If you have trouble grasping the concept, put  `element {border: solid black}`  into all your css elements and you'll see what I mean.

There are multiple displays will only get into the 3 of the arguably most important ones: block, inline, inline-block.

Block: element will take up the maximum amount of horizontal space necessary. Think of the  `li`  as an example. The list point will take up the maximum amount of horizontal space, and thus each separate li can be considered a block.

Inline: element will take up the minimum amount of horizontal, and vertical space necessary to fit within the flow. Think of the anchor  `a`  tag, as it will take up the minimum amount of space necessary to fit within the flow of a paragraph.

Inline-block: Considered an inline  value but with the ability to change the width and height of the element.

For your example, I have used the relative positioning element (positioned it right 12px relative to where it originally was) and changed the display to be inline-block, as divs are naturally block elements and thus, without the inline-block display feature, they would have only stacked 1 at a time.